# Folder 's"Date modified" incorrect (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

Something very odd is going on with the "date modified" field of several folders on an exFAT external drive I have. A folder in which several files were recently added is still showing its date modified as its creation date. Even worse, another folder with recently added files is showing a date that *precedes* its creation date! Has anyone observed this and know what might be going on? I have checked online and found nothing useful/relevant regarding this. The same information shows up in both Explorer and in a command prompt so its not specific to Explorer

Comment: Can you provide the dates where last modification date is before creation date? Are we talking about seconds, minutes, hours, days? Are you sure that no one played with the clock?

Answer (score 0):

Run this PowerShell script. Close Explorer before running to avoid file-locking.

```
 # -------------give each folder the highest modified date of it's files --------
 function OneDir($dir)
 {
     # elaborate one folder, with given name
     Set-Location -Path $dir.FullName
     $maxd = Get-Date(0)
     $files = Get-ChildItem  -Recurse -Filter *.* | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer -eq $false } 
     for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) 
     {
         $file = $files[$i]
         $cd = [datetime]($file.lastwritetime)
          If ($cd -Gt $maxd) 
             {$maxd = $cd}
     }
     If ($files.Count -Gt 0) 
         {$dir.LastWriteTime = ($maxd)}
     Write-Host ($dir.FullName) +  " " + ($dir.LastWriteTime)
 }
 #------------------------- main ------------------------------------
 $startDir = Read-Host 'Foldername to start with'
 Set-Location -Path $startDir 
 $t = Get-ItemProperty $startDir
 OneDir $t
 $dirs = Get-ChildItem  -Recurse -Filter *.* | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } 
 for ($d=0; $d -lt $dirs.Count; $d++) 
 {
     OneDir $dirs[$d]
 } 
 Write-Host "Finished. press Enter"
 cmd /c pause
```